# insert into mysql syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am trying to insert a new values into my Place table, but I am get an error that the syntax incorrect.

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000)

In the Place table I have four fields one is the ID that is primary key, auto increment and the the other is recognize, name and place and they are only not null.

```
sql.query_insert("""insert into Place('RECOGNIZE','NAME','PLACE') values ('QsDyNOZG9n','test1','test2')""")
```

create table statement -

```
CREATE TABLE `Place`.`Place` (
`ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`RECOGNIZE` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`NAME` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`PLACE` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));
```

How can I find where the problem occurs ? And how to fix that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try replacing single quotes for column names with back ticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
sql.query_insert("""insert into Place.Place(`RECOGNIZE`,`NAME`,`PLACE`)
                    values ('QsDyNOZG9n','test1','test2')""")
```

use `` instead ''

Comment: Thanks !!! It's work

Comment: may this is useful to you https://www.sublimetext.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it as such..

```
("insert into Place.Place (RECOGNIZE, NAME, PLACE) values ('QsDyNOZG9n','test1','test2')")
```

I think you have too many quotes in place and the space between the table 'place' and the column names need to be there. Let me know if that works..

Comment: Thanks ! It's work perfect maybe this is was the problem